# Why jetpack compose elevation clip my shadow?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a problem with jetpack compose elevation render. I'm trying to add elevation on Surface but my UI seems to with clipped shadow. Also, how can I add a colorful shadow on my Surface?

See the below on the screenshot
[image]

```
@Composable
fun DiscoverItem() {
    Surface(
        contentColor = Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
        modifier = Modifier.preferredWidthIn(min = 145.dp).preferredHeight(56.dp),
        shape = CircleShape,
        elevation = 8.dp,
    ) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().padding(horizontal = 8.dp),
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {
            Surface(
                modifier = Modifier.preferredSize(40.dp),
                shape = CircleShape,
                color = Color(0xFFFFC3D8)
            ) {
                Image(
                    imageResource(R.drawable.pin_icon),
                    modifier = Modifier.size(width = 18.dp, height = 24.dp),
                    contentScale = ContentScale.Fit
                )
            }
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 10.dp))
            Text(
                "YOUR AREA",
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2,
                color = Color(0xFFFC1055)
            )
        }
    }
}

@Composable
@Preview
fun DiscoverItemPreview() {
    DiscoverItem()
}
```

Comment: Have you added vertical padding to the parent composable that contains `DiscoverItem`?

Comment: @SaurabhThorat yes but when you give padding your component you must think about other layout spacing. Why we need padding for that elevation? For example, react native view can get elevation without padding.

Comment: Why don't use the card instead of Surface? If you go deeper you will see the Card is using Surface underneath as well
@Melih Berberoglu

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't have enough content on bottom of your layout. You can add spacer to view your shadow.

```
@Composable
@Preview
fun DiscoverItemPreview() {
    Column{
    DiscoverItem()
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))
    }
}
```

And about colorful shadow, compose min sdk is Android Lollpop and skia version for lollipop doesnot supports colorful shadow/elevation. Leland Richardson had talked about this issue in his youtube video on Compose dogfooding. [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2j08MEbA6cs&list=PLcgGtmZOsTwErUfFxtjLWAyzes1Oj7wzo)

Comment: This is not a solution, but workaround. You should never solve problems this way. Right way to solve this is to use `LazyColumn`'s `contentPadding` (check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66436050/11535782))

Answer (score 4):

I use surface to wrap the shadowed card and it gives me expected result.

```
 Surface(
    elevation = 4.dp,
    color = MaterialTheme.colors.surface,
    shape = Shapes.medium,
) {
    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .animateContentSize(
                animationSpec = tween(
                    durationMillis = 300,
                    easing = LinearOutSlowInEasing
                )
            ),
        elevation = 8.dp,
        shape = Shapes.medium,
        onClick = {
            isExpanded = !isExpanded
        }

    ) {}}
```

[preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqcRF.png)