# Padding clips scaled element on top, but not (really) on the side

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am making a grid layout using `LazyColumn` and `Row`s. I also want to scale one element at a time. The problem appears when the scaled element is on the edge as it gets (at least partially) clipped.

Why does it happen on the top, but not as much on the side? How to correct that?

Is this the expected behavior (and therefore my code is faulty) or perhaps a bug in Jetpack Compose?

```kotlin
private const val NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS = 5
private val SPACING = 20.dp

@Composable
fun MainScreen(
    elements: List<String>,
) {
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color.Blue)
            .padding(50.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Absolute.spacedBy(SPACING)
    ) {
        val numberOfRows = ceil(elements.size / NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS.toFloat()).roundToInt()
        for (rowIndex in 0 until numberOfRows) {
            item {
                Row(
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Absolute.spacedBy(SPACING)
                ) {
                    for (columnIndex in 0 until NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS) {
                        val itemIndex = (rowIndex * NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS) + columnIndex
                        if (itemIndex < elements.size) {
                            GridElement(
                                text = elements[itemIndex]
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun GridElement(
    text: String,
) {
    val scale by remember {
        mutableStateOf(
            if (text == "1" || text == "9" || text == "11") 1.6f else 1f
        )
    }
    val zIndex by remember {
        mutableStateOf(
            if (text == "1" || text == "9" || text == "11") 30f else 0f
        )
    }

    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(width = 130.dp, height = 100.dp)
            .graphicsLayer(
                scaleX = scale,
                scaleY = scale,
            )
            .zIndex(zIndex = zIndex),
        border = BorderStroke(width = 1.dp, Color.Red),
    ) {
        Text(text = text)
    }
}

@Preview(
    backgroundColor = 0x666666,
    widthDp = 900,
    heightDp = 500,
)
@Composable
private fun MainScreenPreview() {
    MaterialTheme {
        MainScreen(
            (1 until 14).map { it.toString() },
        )
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Result of the code above]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for the clipping problem itself:

Instead of using `Modifier.padding()` on `LazyColumn` I used `Lazycolumn`s `contentPadding` parameter:

```
LazyColumn(
    modifier = Modifier
        .background(Color.Blue)
        .padding(50.dp),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Absolute.spacedBy(SPACING),
    contentPadding = PaddingValues(50.dp),
)
```

What I needed to do, but didn't realize immediately, was to disable `clipToPadding`. I found the solution based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66436050/6835732).