# Prevent shadow clipping without adding content padding in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66435811/jetpack-compose-cliptopadding/66436050#66436050) notes that in order to not clip the shadows on a `LazyRow`/`LazyColumn` in Jetpack Compose you need to add `ContentPadding`. However, I want to do the equivalent of `"clipToPadding=false"` without adding additional padding (the padding should be `0.dp`). Is this possible? Or do you have to have some sort of `1.dp` padding around the object?

Ex:

```
LazyRow(
        state = listState,
        flingBehavior = flingBehavior,
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(all = 0.dp)
    )
```

See clipping shadows on the lefthand edge:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

---

```
LazyRow(
    state = listState,
    flingBehavior = flingBehavior,
    contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 0.dp)
) {
    items(itemsList) { item ->
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(horizontal = 8.dp) // add small padding to each item
                .drawWithContent {
                    drawContent() // draw the content
                    drawRect(
                        color = Color.Black, // define your shadow color
                        size = Size(size.width, 16f), // adjust shadow size
                        style = Shadow(style = ShadowStyle.Cut), // set the shadow style
                        shape = RectangleShape, // use a shape
                        topLeft = Offset(x = 0f, y = size.height - 16f) // set shadow offset
                    )
                }
        ) {
            // your content
        }
    }
}
```

---