# How can we define ClipToPadding in Jetpack compose as well?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, cliptobounds

How can we define **ClipToPadding** in Jetpack compose as well?
Consider we have a card component that inside of it we have buttons with shadow, how can we have the `ClipToPadding=false` in Compose?

Comment: See [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64297491/why-jetpack-compose-elevation-clip-my-shadow) and [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66435811/jetpack-compose-cliptopadding).